# IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2, when applying vectorizer.transform function

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

when i am trying to transform the CV data it is resulting in the error `"IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2".`
I have already used the fit function on the train data but  the issue is occurring when we are using the transform function on CV data.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2,ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=5000)
text_tfidf = vectorizer.fit(X_train['project_title']) # fit has to happen only on train data

# we use the fitted CountVectorizer to convert the text to vector
X_train_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_train['project_title'].values)
X_cv_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_cv['project_title'].values)
X_test_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_test['project_title'].values)

below is the error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-d199fe946811> in <module>
      8 # we use the fitted CountVectorizer to convert the text to vector
      9 X_train_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_train['project_title'].values)
---> 10 X_cv_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_cv['project_title'].values)
     11 X_test_project_title_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_test['project_title'].values)
     12 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     33     """
     34     def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 35         row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
     36         # Dispatch to specialized methods.
     37         if isinstance(row, INT_TYPES):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in _validate_indices(self, key)
    138                 row += M
    139         elif not isinstance(row, slice):
--> 140             row = self._asindices(row, M)
    141 
    142         if isintlike(col):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py in _asindices(self, idx, length)
    162 
    163         if x.ndim not in (1, 2):
--> 164             raise IndexError('Index dimension must be <= 2')
    165 
    166         if x.size == 0:

IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2
```

Comment: why you are doing `vectorizer.transform(X_cv['project_title'].values)`. Try with `vectorizer.transform(X_cv['project_title'])`

Answer (score 1):

`X_cv['project_title']` is expected to have different dimensions. Than what is given.
check if you have used the SAME variable name `X_cv` for two different variables.